# How Much RAM Should I Put On My Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, ram

I am installing virtual box on my window

I will use it for anonymous web browsing and nothing else.

I will also install ccleaner on the VM.

The total Amount is 2GB.

How much ram should I put on my Virtual Machine?

Which version of window is the best for Anonymous Web Browsing?

Is linux a better option for anonymity web browsing?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is, therefore, off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think this belongs on superuser.com. It'll probably be migrated there.

Comment: Any browser with Privacy Mode is pretty good for anonymous browsing, but your ISP knows *exactly* what you are doing and can check if served a warrant (in most jurisdictions).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Joe. You should try to break up your question into one answerable problem per question. Questions that ask for "the best," or general recommendations are not a good fit for SO's Q&A model. Give the [faq] a read for help on asking questions here.

Comment: I agree with everyone prior to me here that it is off topic for programming, but virtual box is essential tool for most programmers and if he was asking it in a way that relates to QA or Production setup for a program he wrote... we don't need to be the smart smurf in each opportunity we get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though i agree with above comments, it doesn't hurt to add some info. I take that you mean you have 2GB Ram in total.

First, the amount of ram required is proportional to how much you actually use it(VM) for and whether will you be using your primary machine in parallel or not.

For e.g. i have a 64 bit system windows 7 with 8 GB ram. I frequently use 1 linux VM in parallel with my host machine. So i have dedicated 2GB per VM. Though i have multiple VM's, it is almost guaranteed that i don't use two VM's simultaneously. However, i am extensively using VM + host together.

Now if you are going to do a lot of browsing, that probably means a lot of tabs, perhaps including you tube videos and stuff. Since your total is 2GB, i won't recommended allocating more than 512MB to your VM, unless you are willing to sacrifice your host performance for the time you are running VM.

Anonymous browsing has little to do with OS rather more important is browser or intermediate application. The only possible difference is for e.g. if you are using Linux and use an open source application such as 
[tor](http://www.torproject.org/)
which may or may not be available on windows. [Edit: just verified that tor does exist on windows too]

CCleaner is of no use if you are already using a common feature of FF/Ch/IE "Start private browsing". However, this does not leave any thing in your history and cache.

I also believe you are some what confusing anonymous browsing. Use of VM or CCcleaner refers to anonymity which is local to your machine i.e. if some one else uses your pc, he/she would not be able to track what you have been doing by ordinary means.

However, your real ip and request info is not hidden from your network in general. Using of Tor or some proxies etc. results in network anonymity where you leave no trace on a site which you have visited or perhaps that is blocked in your region.

Another thing is, if you have a 32bit machine / OS which is windows, it doesn't utilize more than 3GB ram in practice.

Comment: Hi, I already have private proxies to hide my real IP.

Comment: But the real concern for me is flash cookie or LSO. They are shared on the same computer and even if I change browser or use private browsing, website can still track me. Virtual Machine is the easiest way to get rid of those flash cookies.

Answer (score 0):

regarding ram: 0.5 gb should be enough but in any case virtual box recomends those values when you telling it what you about to install on the vm.

Windows 7 is best os I seen comming out from MS house till today especially in security.

IE9 private browsing can do what you ask for without a vm at all.